# How to separate javascript into files without using global scope?

Tags: javascript, oop

I am loading separate .js files into my html page. These files use anonymous functions so that the global scope is not filled with global variables. For example: this is my 'utils.js' file:

```
(function(window){
   var Utils = {
       createURL: function() {
           console.log("creating url");
       }
   };
})(window);
```

My question: if I have several of these .js files, how can they reference each other without using the global scope? As it stands, I can only call this function from within the same utils.js file:

```
var myUtils = new Utils();
```

Comment: Have a look at [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: You sure you are not getting an error Utils is not a constructor with the code you have got?

Comment: You can use namespaces.  Look here for details : http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/04/27/javascript-namespaces-and-modules/

Comment: You always will need to use the global scope somehow, otherwise you cannot set up any connection between the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function(window){
   var app = {};
    app.Utils = {
        createUrl:function(){}
    };
    window.app = app;
})(window);
```

and then you can work with the app like this :

```
app.Utils.createUrl();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create global modules and expose only the needed functions like this...

```
// In some JS file
var moduleX = (function(window){
   var Utils = function(){

   };

   return {
       "Utils" : Utils
   };
})(window);

// In a some other JS file
var util = new moduleX.Utils();
```

Btw, you cannot instantiate a JSON object(`Utils` in your case). So please change that to a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a javascript loader like

- [`require.js`](http://requirejs.org/)
- [`head.js`](http://yepnopejs.com/)
- [`yepnope`](http://headjs.com/)

If you don't want to use a loader, maybe you can reduce the global usage to the minimun using a [design pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) like the [mediator](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#mediatorpatternjavascript) or [module](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a third party tool, you can wrap everything into one module by using the following pattern:

```
//file1
var myModule = (function(window, that){

    var myVar = 1;

    that.myMethod1 = function(){
        console.log("i am module 1");
    };

    return that;
}(window, myModule || {}));

//file2
var myModule = (function(window, that){

    that.myMethod2 = function(){
        console.log(typeof myVar); //undefined
        that.myMethod1();   //i am module 1
    };

    return that;
}(window, myModule || {}));
```

This will ensure that you only have one single global variable. But, you will of course not be able to access local variables of another file.

Comment: thanks. I've written it slightly differently, like this:
window.MAINAPP = {};
and then, I attach every anonymous function to MAINAPP, like this:
MAINAPP.myModule = myModule;